# Unity Check overlap of rect works except if in gridlayoutgroup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grid-layout, overlapping, inventory

So for my scene I have an `Item` and a `Slot` script. If the `Slot` script is applied to UI in `GridLayoutGroup` it doesn't read, even if it is hovering or not. However if Slot UI object is not inside`GridLayoutGroup` it reads overlap fine.

Below are the scripts. I am basing scale on 35px currently for testing.

Slot.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IDropHandler
{

    public RectTransform Item_DragRect
    {
        get
        {
            if(Item_CS.Item_Dragged != null)
            {
                return Item_CS.Item_Dragged.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    public RectTransform rectTransform;
    public Rect DisplayRect;

    public Color D_Color;
    public Color O_Color;
    public Color T_Color;
    public GameObject CurrItem;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rectTransform = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        DisplayRect = new Rect(rectTransform.localPosition.x, rectTransform.localPosition.y, rectTransform.rect.width, rectTransform.rect.height);
        if (Item_DragRect != null)
        {
            CurrItem = Item_DragRect.gameObject;
            Rect myRect = new Rect(rectTransform.localPosition.x, rectTransform.localPosition.y, rectTransform.rect.width, rectTransform.rect.height);
            Rect ItemRect = new Rect(Item_DragRect.localPosition.x, Item_DragRect.localPosition.y, Item_DragRect.rect.width, Item_DragRect.rect.height);

            if (ItemRect.Overlaps(myRect))
            {
                GetComponent<Image>().color = O_Color;
            }
            else
            {
                GetComponent<Image>().color = D_Color;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CurrItem = null;
            GetComponent<Image>().color = D_Color;
        }
    }
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }
}
```

Item_CS.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Item_CS : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public static GameObject Item_Dragged;
    public GameObject CurrID;
    public Vector2 MyScale;
    private Vector3 ItemPos;




    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RectTransform rectTransform = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(MyScale.x * 35, MyScale.y * 35);
        DragFunction();
        CurrID = Item_Dragged;
    }

    public void DragFunction()
    {
        if(Item_Dragged != null)
        {
            Item_Dragged.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
        }
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(Item_Dragged == null)
        {
            Item_Dragged = gameObject;
            GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Item_Dragged = gameObject;
            GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        this.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;       
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Item_Dragged = null;
        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out it was because of parent object had cancel out its transform as far as position by adding it to current so added a simple check see if slot parent has gridlayoutgrid if so to cancel out the difference

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IDropHandler
{

    public RectTransform Item_DragRect
    {
        get
        {
            if(Item_CS.Item_Dragged != null)
            {
                return Item_CS.Item_Dragged.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    public RectTransform rectTransform;
    public RectTransform rectParent;
    public Rect DisplayRect;

    public Color D_Color;
    public Color O_Color;
    public Color T_Color;
    public GameObject CurrItem;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rectTransform = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        if(GetComponentInParent<GridLayoutGroup>() != null)
        {
            rectParent = GetComponentInParent<GridLayoutGroup>().GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        }
        else
        {
            rectParent = null;
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        DisplayRect = new Rect(rectTransform.transform.position.x, rectTransform.transform.position.y, rectTransform.rect.width, rectTransform.rect.height);
        if (Item_DragRect != null)
        {
            CurrItem = Item_DragRect.gameObject;
            if(rectParent != null)
            {
                Rect myRect = new Rect(rectTransform.localPosition.x + rectParent.localPosition.x, rectTransform.localPosition.y + rectParent.localPosition.y, rectTransform.rect.width, rectTransform.rect.height);
                Rect ItemRect = new Rect(Item_DragRect.localPosition.x, Item_DragRect.localPosition.y, Item_DragRect.rect.width, Item_DragRect.rect.height);

                if (ItemRect.Overlaps(myRect))
                {
                    GetComponent<Image>().color = O_Color;
                }
                else
                {
                    GetComponent<Image>().color = D_Color;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Rect myRect = new Rect(rectTransform.localPosition.x, rectTransform.localPosition.y, rectTransform.rect.width, rectTransform.rect.height);
                Rect ItemRect = new Rect(Item_DragRect.localPosition.x, Item_DragRect.localPosition.y, Item_DragRect.rect.width, Item_DragRect.rect.height);

                if (ItemRect.Overlaps(myRect))
                {
                    GetComponent<Image>().color = O_Color;
                }
                else
                {
                    GetComponent<Image>().color = D_Color;
                }
            }


        }
        else
        {
            CurrItem = null;
            GetComponent<Image>().color = D_Color;
        }
    }
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RectTransform is quite tricky. Your localPosition will vary depending on anchors you set. You should debug and check if localPosition returns desired values, also localPosition never worked for me when using RectTransform, I don't think you should use it with RectTransform, I suppose it's property inherited from Transform and you should probably use anchoredPosition and pivot to calculate your rect position.

Check out image. Im just logging localPosition of that rectTransform and it's total bullshit, I have no idea how 146,-300 became -574, 1180, scale of my CanvasScaller is 4.95 so it does not calculate in any way
[image: Example1 localPosition on Awake]

Anchored position, on the other hand, works exactly as expected:
[image: Example2 anchoredPosition on Awake]

Comment: My mistake i made scale of 35px sound bit weird the 35 scale is size of cells in the grid and size item is based on

Comment: item is on same level as UI that controls grid size slots script is applied to cells in the grid